# Parsing Nested JSON column in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have a below sample data,as a dataframe

```
id|data
1,{"a":["xyz","x"],"b":["abc","ab"]}
2,{"a":["zy","y"],"b":["ac","bc"]}
```

This is my expected output:

```
id|details
1,abc
2,ac
```

This is what I have come with till now,

```
dataframe.withColumn("details",from_json($"data",StructType(Seq(StructField("b",ArrayType(StringType),true)))))
```

This is the output I am getting right now

```
1,[abc,ab]
2,[ac,bc]
```

Also, this is just a sample, I have more than 100 columns so cannot use select clause. Want to resolve this using withColumn.

Comment: Can you explain how the expected output is calculated ? For example, why id "2" has details "22" ?

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have the first element of the `b` array, based on `details` column you have already computed, simply select the first element of `b`:

```
 dataframe.withColumn("details", expr("details.b[0]"))
```

You also can use `getField` and `getItem` functions directly on the result of `from_json`

```
dataframe.withColumn("details",from_json($"data",StructType(Seq(StructField("b",ArrayType(StringType),true)))).getField("b").getItem(0))
```

Comment: Its working, but I m looking for a way to use only one with column and achieve this result.